# Unable to open the existing database in android

Tags: android, sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

For my application, I already have a readymade database (i.e. it's stored in the assets folder named example.sqlite with value inserted into it.)

This is the my class Database Helper ::

```
package com.huskerit.util;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

import com.huskerit.model.AllSportData;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper  {
//private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// Table name
public static final String TABLE = "all_team";
public static final String TABLE_SELECTED = "selected_team";
// Columns
public static final String ID = "id";
public static final String NAME = "name";
public static final String CATEGORY1 = "category1";
public static final String CATEGORY2 = "category2";

public static SQLiteDatabase database;
private final Context myContext;

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) 
{
    super(context, Constant.DB_NAME, null, 1);
    this.myContext = context;
}

public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
{
}

public void createDataBase() throws IOException
{
    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
    System.out.println("~~~~~~~~"+dbExist);
    if(dbExist)
    {
        //do nothing - database already exist
    }
    else
    {
        //By calling this method and empty database will be created into the default system path
        //of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that database with our database.
        DatabaseHelper.this.getReadableDatabase();
        try 
        {
            this.close();   
            copyDataBase();
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file
 * each time you open the application.
 * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
 */
private boolean checkDataBase()
{
    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

    try
    {
        String myPath = Constant.DB_PATH + Constant.DB_NAME;
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

    }
    catch(SQLiteException e)
    {
        //database does't exist yet.
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if(checkDB != null)
    {
        checkDB.close();
    }

    return checkDB != null ? true : false;
}

/**
 * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created empty database in the
 * system folder, from where it can be accessed and handled.
 * This is done by transfering bytestream.
 * */
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{
    //Open your local db as the input stream

    // Path to the just created empty db
    String outFileName = Constant.DB_PATH + Constant.DB_NAME;

    //Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
    InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(Constant.DB_NAME);
    //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
    myInput.close();
    //Close the streams
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
}

public void openDataBase() throws SQLException
{
    //Open the database
    String myPath = Constant.DB_PATH + Constant.DB_NAME;
    database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath,null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
}

public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) 
{
}
}
```

Now I am calling the database in my activity like this ::

```
public class TeamSelectActivity extends Activity
{

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_teamselect);

    if(Constant.mDatabase == null)
    {
        Constant.mDatabase = new DatabaseHelper(TeamSelectActivity.this);
    }


    try 
    {
        //Constant.mDatabase.createDataBase(); //DataBase();
        Constant.mDatabase.openDataBase();
    } 
    catch (SQLException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

This is the my log trace ::

```
I/Database(13203): sqlite returned: error code = 14, msg = cannot open file at source line 25467
E/Database(13203): sqlite3_open_v2("/data/data/com.huskerit.login/databases/wimbim.sqlite",  &handle, 2, NULL) failed
W/System.err(13203): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unable to open database file
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.dbopen(Native Method)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.<init>(SQLiteDatabase.java:1849)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:820)
at com.huskerit.util.DatabaseHelper.openDataBase(DatabaseHelper.java:130)
at com.huskerit.login.TeamSelectActivity.onCreate(TeamSelectActivity.java:93)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I am unable to figure it out where i am doing wrong ..
Any help would be appreciated ..

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109438/how-to-use-existing-database-with-android-app/9109728#9109728

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is due to the method checkDataBase(). 
            use the following to check the data

```
         private boolean checkDataBase() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         File dbFile = new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
         return dbFile.exists();
    }
```

Comment: but to open the database i am using this ::
checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);where first parameter is string so how can i pass the file instead of string ?? u got my point ?

Comment: can you point me out where should i write this piece of code as i am newbie to android?

Comment: no dear, i have replaced my checkDatabase() method with your but still getting the same error.... any other clue?

Comment: Thanks dear ....... its working bit of change in code and i can see the magic .....